# How to get token before dot('.') at current cursor postion in javascript for autocompletion in codemirror editor?

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

```
function (editor, currentPos) {
    return editor.getTokenAt(currentPos);
}
```

I am designing a code editor for a custom language. So, I want do autocompletion based on mode state. I want to get token before `.` like when we press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> during `hello`. Then, my method should give me `hello` so I can suggest some properties related to it. How can I do this?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking as it's currently written. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: i am desiging a code editor for custom language.
So, i want do autocompletion based on mode state.

I want to get token before "." like when we press ctrl+space during "hello".  then, my method should give me "hello" so i will suggest some properties related to it.

Comment: That's still not a proper question. As @Kmeixner said, elaborate a bit more what you want to achieve, what you have already tried and what's not working as intended.

Comment: @Dolgsthrasir please read details now

Comment: @Kmeixner please read details now

Answer (score 1):

The [javascript-hint](http://codemirror.net/addon/hint/javascript-hint.js) addon does something like this, continuing to get the previous token in a loop until it finds something that is not a property. You probably want code that looks similar.

Comment: in codemirror.js, you will find a function readtoken(). If i will press ctrl+space , it should give me word before dot so i will be able to give suggestion according to that. Currently it is giving only dot in token. please help  if u can

Comment: Read the documentation for [`getTokenAt`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getTokenAt), pay extra attention to where it says that you'll get the token before the position you pass in, and you should be able to make something work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, and i ends using a chunk of code to get the current line and then split'em to get the last token (and the . separator):

```
autocomplete(cm) {
   let full_line = cm.getValue();
   let end = cm.getCursor().ch;
   full_line = full_line.substr(0, end);
   let start = full_line.lastIndexOf(" ");

   if (start === -1) {
     start = 0;
   }

   let currentWord = full_line.substr(start, end - start);
   console.log(currentWord);

[...]
```

You can see the complete code in my ember-plugin: https://github.com/hugoruscitti/ember-cli-jsconsole/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/controllers/application.js#L5